# Windows Form Custom User Control not visible in design mode

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have created my own custom user control and is working just fine in debug mode. The problem is that when i add it in a design mode the back color of the form and the control is the same so when i deselect the control it is very difficult to re-select it as i need to remember where exactly i put it in the form.

Is there a method that will help? For example is there a code that i can write in the custom control that it will make it visible (like changing the back color of the control in design view only)

Comment: You tend to fall in the pit of success by giving the UserControl some content.  If it has nothing to show then you should almost surely derive your class from Control instead.  And do something interesting in OnPaint() if the DesignMode property is true.

Comment: sorry but i didnt get that... can u give me a code example?

Comment: I cannot possibly guess why you used a UserControl but did not put any controls inside of it.  Surely you need to experiment some more to arrive at the correct solution.  Do not be afraid to try deriving your class from Control and override OnPaint, it is core to winforms programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can close the form that contain your custom control (design) and reopen the form.
That's it! When you build project, Custom control become transparent and you can reopen the form, it will fire paint event for you.